# Shortest path to transform one word into another

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path, edit-distance, hamming-distance

For a Data Structures project, I must find the shortest path between two words (like `"cat"` and `"dog"`), changing only one letter at a time. We are given a Scrabble word list to use in finding our path. For example:

```
cat -> bat -> bet -> bot -> bog -> dog
```

I've solved the problem using a breadth first search, but am seeking something better (I represented the dictionary with a trie).

Please give me some ideas for a more efficient method (in terms of speed and memory). Something ridiculous and/or challenging is preferred.

I asked one of my friends (he's a junior) and he said that there is *no* efficient solution to this problem. He said I would learn why when I took the algorithms course. Any comments on that?

We must move from word to word.  We cannot go `cat -> dat -> dag -> dog`.  We also have to print out the traversal.

Comment: In your example, why is bet in there?  You changed the same letter twice in a row, it should read: 
cat -> bat -> bot -> bog -> dog

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811918/how-to-compute-shortest-distance-between-two-words/11813399#11813399

Comment: Dacman, would you mind sharing how much your performance improved using the heuristics vs. BFS?

Comment: On a side note, the shortest path from cat to dog is cat >> cot >> cog >> dog :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**NEW ANSWER**

Given the recent update, you could try A* with the Hamming distance as a heuristic. It's an admissible heuristic since it's not going to overestimate the distance

**OLD ANSWER**

You can modify the dynamic-program used to compute the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) to obtain the sequence of operations.

EDIT: If there are a constant number of strings, the problem is solvable in polynomial time. Else, it's NP-hard (it's all there in wikipedia) .. assuming your friend is talking about the problem being NP-hard.

EDIT: If your strings are of equal length, you can use [Hamming distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance).

Comment: Given the example that should be Hamming distance.

Comment: You can't modify the Levenshtein function to do this, because you have a limited dictionary of valid words - and so the shortest valid path could be very much longer than the number of characters in the string.

Comment: Right, the word->word concept was only clear in the recent edit.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that.  What if I were to use a Branch and Bound algorithm, using the Hamming distance to bound?

Comment: I was thinking of A* with the Hamming distance as a heuristic. It's definitely admissible since it's not going to overestimate the distance.

Comment: This depends on how you're measuring runtime. A* could get there faster - but in pathological cases, it could also take longer than the BFS (or dual BFS - see my answer) solution.

Comment: *shameless plug* I actually asked a question a month or two ago about this problem except in Python, and I ended up using A* with Hamming distance as the heuristic (although I didn't know it was called Hamming Distance at the time). I got some really good optimizations (some python specific, some not).  The question is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/788084/how-can-i-optimize-this-python-code and in the question updates I linked to a blog-post I made (about halfway down... there were a lot of updates to the question) where I described the optimizations along with the code.

Comment: I did this and it worked wonderfully well.  Amazed my professor too!

Comment: Good to know! Algorithms is always fun :)

Comment: Dacman, would you mind sharing how much your performance improved using the heuristics vs. BFS?

Comment: Jacob, can you say more about why it's admissable.  I had assumed it wasn't for the same reason that @Nick Jonhson gave - i.e. the hamming distance may say that two words have a hamming distance of 2, but the intermediates you need might not be in the dictionary, so the real distance is larger than 2. (e.g. abc -> dbe, with dictionary abc, xbc, xyc, xye, dye, dbe gives hamming distance 2 and minimum path length of 5)

Answer (score 9):

With a dictionary, BFS is optimal, but the running time needed is proportional to its size (V+E). With n letters, the dictionary might have ~a^n entires, where a is alphabet size. If the dictionary contains all words but the one that should be on the end of chain, then you'll traverse all possible words but won't find anything. This is graph traversal, but the size might be exponentially large.

You may wonder if it is possible to do it faster - to browse the structure "intelligently" and do it in polynomial time. The answer is, I think, no.

The problem:

You're given a fast (linear) way to check if a word is in dictionary, two words u, v and are to check if there's a sequence u -> a<sub>1</sub> -> a<sub>2</sub> -> ... -> a<sub>n</sub> -> v.

is NP-hard.

Proof: Take some 3SAT instance, like

(p or q or not r) and (p or not q or r)

You'll start with 0 000 00 and are to check if it is possible to go to 2 222 22.

The first character will be "are we finished", three next bits will control p,q,r and two next will control clauses.

Allowed words are:

- Anything that starts with 0 and contains only 0's and 1's
- Anything that starts with 2 and is legal. This means that it consists of 0's and 1's (except that the first character is 2, all clauses bits are rightfully set according to variables bits, and they're set to 1 (so this shows that the formula is satisfable).
- Anything that starts with at least two 2's and then is composed of 0's and 1's (regular expression: 222* (0+1)*, like 22221101 but not 2212001

To produce 2 222 22 from 0 000 00, you have to do it in this way:

(1) Flip appropriate bits - e.g. 0 100 111 in four steps. This requires finding a 3SAT solution.

(2) Change the first bit to 2: 2 100 111. Here you'll be verified this is indeed a 3SAT solution.

(3) Change 2 100 111 -> 2 200 111 -> 2 220 111 -> 2 222 111 -> 2 222 211 -> 2 222 221 -> 2 222 222.

These rules enforce that you can't cheat (check). Going to 2 222 22 is possible only if the formula is satisfable, and checking that is NP-hard. I feel it might be even harder (#P or FNP probably) but NP-hardness is enough for that purpose I think.

**Edit**: You might be interested in [disjoint set data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure). This will take your dictionary and group words that can be reached from each other. You can also store a path from every vertex to root or some other vertex. This will give you a path, not neccessarily the shortest one.

Comment: Great summary. If the original author is looking for something really creative, the edit distance can be used in conjunction with the word-reach graph as a fitness function for a genetic algorithm. The output being the path through the graph from one start word to the end word, so the best answer would be the shortest. (While cool, this would find the answer the fastest, but will not yield a definitive answer. Very TS.)

I'd stick with the real world. Eliminate cycles, enumerate the paths   and find the 'best' one using the above suggestions. This is tagged 'Java' so try JGraphT.

Comment: Cool, not often does one see NP-hardness proofs in Stackoverflow answers. :-) I too suspect this problem is harder than NP (PSPACE-complete?) if the dictionary is given simply as a membership oracle... but if the dictionary is actually given in the input, then the problem can trivially be done in polynomial time, as the dictionary size is part of the input (that's the flaw in your NP-hardness proof).

Answer (score 3):

There are methods of varying efficiency for *finding* links - you can construct a complete graph for each word length, or you can construct a [BK-Tree](http://blog.notdot.net/2007/4/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Part-1-BK-Trees), for example, but your friend is right - BFS is the most efficient algorithm.

There is, however, a way to significantly improve your runtime: Instead of doing a single BFS from the source node, do two breadth first searches, starting at either end of the graph, and terminating when you find a common node in their frontier sets. The amount of work you have to do is roughly half what is required if you search from only one end.

Comment: Note that this method only works for unweighted graphs, I believe. On weighted graphs (where some edges are "more cost" or longer than others), using a bi-directional search in the same manner doesn't guarantee the shortest path as been found. Check out [this link](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr06/cos423/Handouts/EPP%20shortest%20path%20algorithms.pdf) and [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253413/termination-criteria-for-bidirectional-search). But in this case, the steps between one-letter-different words are all the same

Answer (score 2):

You can make it a little quicker by removing the words that are not the right length, first.  More of the limited dictionary will fit into the CPU's cache.  Probably all of it.

Also, all of the strncmp comparisons (assuming you made everything lowercase) can be memcmp comparisons, or even unrolled comparisons, which can be a speedup.

You could use some preprocessor magic and hard-compile the task for that word-length, or roll a few optimized variations of the task for common word lengths.  All of those extra comparisons can 'go away' for pure unrolled fun.

Answer (score 0):

You could find the longest common subsequence, and therefore finding the letters that must be changed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) problem.  Check for the Edit Distance problem.

Comment: No it is not. Read the question carefully. There is a fixed given dictionary, so the edit distance has very little relevance.

Answer (score 0):

My gut feeling is that your friend is correct, in that there isn't a more efficient solution, but that is assumming you are reloading the dictionary every time. If you were to keep a running database of common transitions, then surely there would be a more efficient method for finding a solution, but you would need to generate the transitions beforehand, and discovering which transitions would be useful (since you can't generate them all!) is probably an art of its own.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called the Edit Distance. There are many different types.

From (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance): "In information theory and computer science, the edit distance between two strings of characters is the number of operations required to transform one of them into the other."

This article about Jazzy (the java spell check API) has a nice overview of these sorts of comparisons (it's a similar problem - providing suggested corrections) http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jazzy/

Answer (score 0):

```
bool isadjacent(string& a, string& b)
{
  int count = 0;  // to store count of differences
  int n = a.length();

  // Iterate through all characters and return false
  // if there are more than one mismatching characters
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    if (a[i] != b[i]) count++;
    if (count > 1) return false;
  }
  return count == 1 ? true : false;
}
```

// A queue item to store word and minimum chain length
// to reach the word.

```
struct QItem
{
  string word;
  int len;
};
```

// Returns length of shortest chain to reach 'target' from 'start'
// using minimum number of adjacent moves.  D is dictionary

```
int shortestChainLen(string& start, string& target, set<string> &D)
{
  // Create a queue for BFS and insert 'start' as source vertex
  queue<QItem> Q;
  QItem item = {start, 1};  // Chain length for start word is 1
  Q.push(item);

  // While queue is not empty
  while (!Q.empty())
  {
    // Take the front word
    QItem curr = Q.front();
    Q.pop();

    // Go through all words of dictionary
    for (set<string>::iterator it = D.begin(); it != D.end(); it++)
    {
        // Process a dictionary word if it is adjacent to current
        // word (or vertex) of BFS
        string temp = *it;
        if (isadjacent(curr.word, temp))
        {
            // Add the dictionary word to Q
            item.word = temp;
            item.len = curr.len + 1;
            Q.push(item);

            // Remove from dictionary so that this word is not
            // processed again.  This is like marking visited
            D.erase(temp);

            // If we reached target
            if (temp == target)
              return item.len;
        }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

// Driver program
int main()
{
  // make dictionary
  set<string> D;
  D.insert("poon");
  D.insert("plee");
  D.insert("same");
  D.insert("poie");
  D.insert("plie");
  D.insert("poin");
  D.insert("plea");
  string start = "toon";
  string target = "plea";
  cout << "Length of shortest chain is: "
       << shortestChainLen(start, target, D); 
  return 0; 
}
```

Copied from: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/word-ladder-length-of-shortest-chain-to-reach-a-target-word/

Answer (score 0):

This is LeetCode [127. Word Ladder](https://leetcode.com/problems/word-ladder/). The shortest path from source to destination can be found using BFS, but the challenge is finding the next nodes to visit in an efficient manner.
One option is to walk through the dictionary for every word and compare characters pairwise to find out if they differ by 1, but it takes O(mn<sup>2</sup>) time, where `m` is the length of a word and `n` is the number of words in the dictionary.
Instead, we observe that a word "cat" can be transformed in "_at", "c_t", and "ca_", where `_` denotes any character. Thus, we create a mapping of each these wildcard variations to the actual word. During the BFS, the next nodes to visit are given by the words corresponding to all wildcard variations of the word popped from the queue.

Time Complexity: There are `m` wildcard variations of a word of length `m`, so, wildcards takes O(m<sup>2</sup>) time for each string (technically, since it's a generator, it's only O(m<sup>2</sup>) when consumed). If there are `n` words in the dictionary, creating the graph takes O(nm<sup>2</sup>) time.
The BFS is harder to estimate but LeetCode restricts `m` to 10, so, the BFS has an upper bound of `O(n)`.

Python implementation:

```
def word_ladder(begin: str, end: str, dictionary: list[str]) -> list[str]:
    def wildcards(i: int) -> Iterator[str]:
        word = dictionary[i]
        for j in range(len(word)):
            yield f"{word[:j]}_{word[j + 1:]}"

    if end not in dictionary:
        return []
    graph: dict[str, list[int]] = defaultdict(list)
    for i in range(len(dictionary)):
        for w in wildcards(i):
            graph[w].append(i)

    dictionary.append(begin)

    to_visit = deque([(len(dictionary) - 1, -1)])
    visited: set[int] = set()
    path: dict[int, int] = {}
    end_idx = -1
    while to_visit:
        word, parent = to_visit.popleft()
        if word in visited:
            continue
        visited.add(word)
        path[word] = parent
        if dictionary[word] == end:
            end_idx = word
            break
        for w in wildcards(word):
            for neighbor in graph[w]:
                if neighbor not in visited:
                    to_visit.append((neighbor, word))

    result: deque[int] = deque()
    while 0 <= end_idx < len(dictionary):
        result.appendleft(end_idx)
        end_idx = path[end_idx]
    return [dictionary[i] for i in result]
```