# Algorithm to transform one word to another through valid words

Tags: algorithm, string, transform

I came across this variation of [edit-distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) problem:

Design an algorithm which transforms a source word to a target word. for example: from head to tail, in each step, you just can replace one character, and the word must be valid. You'll be given a dictionary.

It clearly is a variation of the [edit distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521958/shortest-path-to-transform-one-word-into-another) problem, but in edit distance I do not care about if the word is valid or not. So how do I add this requirement to edit distance.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This can be modelled as a graph problem. You can think of the words as nodes of the graph and two nodes are connected if and only if they are of same length and differ in one char.

You can preprocess the dictionary and create this graph, should look like:

```
   stack  jack
    |      |
    |      |
   smack  back -- pack -- pick
```

You can then have a mapping from the word to the node representing the word, for this you can use a hash table, height balanced BST ...

Once you have the above mapping in place, all you have to do is see if there exists a path between the two graph nodes, which can easily be done using BFS or DFS.

So you can summarize the algorithm as:

```
preprocess the dictionary and create the graph.
Given the two inputs words w1 and w2
if length(w1) != length(w2)
 Not possible to convert
else
 n1 = get_node(w1)
 n2 = get_node(w2)

 if(path_exists(n1,n2))
   Possible and nodes in the path represent intermediary words
 else
   Not possible
```

Comment: Such graphs are actually being used over at the Russian Wiktionary, see http://ru.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=%D0%A1%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%3ASearch&ns6=1&search=%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC&fulltext=%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA or http://www.aisee.com/graph_of_the_month/words.htm

Comment: This is exactly what I had in mind. I was thinking more in terms of space and time complexity.

Comment: can you explain how many graph i have to generate. is it one or multiple? like in your example whats the relation between "stack" and "jack"? thanks

Comment: Why do you say that if words are not of same length then its not possible to convert? For ex., if given word can be converted to another word by addition of a character and both of them can be valid words, then above solution won't work. (Example: w1= the, w2=them). Correct solution would be to construct graph with connected nodes which are at edit distance of 1.

Comment: @prasadvk The original problem states, "you just can replace one character."  Insertions/deletions are different from replacements.

Comment: any thoughts on how to build the graph?

Answer (score 15):

codaddict's graph approach is valid, though it takes O(n^2) time to build each graph, where n is the number of words of a given length. If that's a problem, you can build a [bk-tree](http://blog.notdot.net/2007/4/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Part-1-BK-Trees) much more efficiently, which makes it possible to find all words with a given edit distance (in this case, 1) of a target word.

Comment: Good one Nick. Thanks a lot for sharing. I really appreciate when people post a good answer to a question thats old and already accepted.

Comment: If you treat maximum word length and alphabet size as constants, you can build each graph in O(n) time.  For a given word, (e.g., "cat"), you can permute the first character ("aat", "bat", "cat", "dat", etc.) and do a hash table lookup to see which are words.  Then you can do the same for the second letter, third letter, etc.  That means you can find all words with an edit distance of 1 from a given word in O(1) time after O(n) preprocessing.  Thus, building a graph of size n would take O(n) time after O(n) preprocessing.

Comment: @JohnKurlak If you hold enough things constant, most algorithms look cheap.

Comment: @NickJohnson That's fair, but in practice it's not a big problem. In the English language, the average word length is about 5 letters, so you're really looking at about 100 constant time operations per word. If that's still too much for you, you can take another approach: have a `Map<String, Map<String, Set<String>>>` that maps `(prefix, suffix)` to a set of words that start with `prefix`, has any letter after that, and then ends with `suffix`. You can build this structure in O(nm^2) time, where n is the dictionary size and m is max word length. That's about 25 operations per word on average.

Answer (score 4):

Create a graph with each node representing word in the dictionary. Add an edge between two word nodes, if their corresponding words are at edit distance of 1. Then minimum number of transformations required would length of shortest path between source node and destination node.

Answer (score 3):

You could simply use recursive back-tracking but this is far from the most optimal solution.

```
# Given two words of equal length that are in a dictionary, write a method to transform one word into another word by changing only
# one letter at a time.  The new word you get in each step must be in the
# dictionary.

# def transform(english_words, start, end):

# transform(english_words, 'damp', 'like')
# ['damp', 'lamp', 'limp', 'lime', 'like']
# ['damp', 'camp', 'came', 'lame', 'lime', 'like']


def is_diff_one(str1, str2):
    if len(str1) != len(str2):
        return False

    count = 0
    for i in range(0, len(str1)):
        if str1[i] != str2[i]:
            count = count + 1

    if count == 1:
        return True

    return False


potential_ans = []


def transform(english_words, start, end, count):
    global potential_ans
    if count == 0:
        count = count + 1
        potential_ans = [start]

    if start == end:
        print potential_ans
        return potential_ans

    for w in english_words:
        if is_diff_one(w, start) and w not in potential_ans:
            potential_ans.append(w)
            transform(english_words, w, end, count)
            potential_ans[:-1]

    return None


english_words = set(['damp', 'camp', 'came', 'lame', 'lime', 'like'])
transform(english_words, 'damp', 'lame', 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is edit distance.

I think this can be done using a graph. Just construct a graph from your dictionary, and attempt to navigate using your favorite graph traversal algorithm to the destination.

Answer (score 1):

@Codeaddict solution is correct but it misses on the opportunity to simplify and optimize the solution.

**DFS vs BFS:**

If we go with DFS, there are chances that we meet `target` string (or `to_string`) far deeper in the graph. Then we have to keep track of the levels at which it is found and the reference to that node, and finally find the minimum level possible and then trace it from root.

For example, consider this conversion `from` -> `zoom`:

```
               from
             /       \  
        fram            foom
        /  \            /   \
    dram    drom     [zoom] food       << To traverse upto this level is enough
 ...         |           ...      
            doom                  
             |       
           [zoom]
```

Using BFS, we can simplify this process by a great deal. All we need to do is :

1. Start with `from` string at level `0`. Add this string to `visitedSetOfStrings`.
2. Add non-visited **valid** strings to next level which are at edit distance +1 from the strings of current level.
3. Add all these strings to `visitedSetOfStrings`.
4. If this set contains the `target` string, stop further processing of nodes/strings. Otherwise continue to step 2.

To make the path tracing easier, we can add extra information of `parent` string in each node.

Comment: this is precise and crisp solution! should be made accepted!

Answer (score 0):

This is C# code to solve the problem using BFS:

```
//use a hash set for a fast check if a word is already in the dictionary
    static HashSet<string> Dictionary = new HashSet<string>();
    //dictionary used to find the parent in every node in the graph and to avoid traversing an already traversed node
    static Dictionary<string, string> parents = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public static List<string> FindPath(List<string> input, string start, string end)
    {
        char[] allcharacters = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};

        foreach (string s in input)
            Dictionary.Add(s);
        List<string> currentFrontier = new List<string>();
        List<string> nextFrontier = new List<string>();
        currentFrontier.Add(start);
        while (currentFrontier.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (string s in currentFrontier)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
                {
                    foreach (char c in allcharacters)
                    {
                        StringBuilder newWordBuilder = new StringBuilder(s);
                        newWordBuilder[i] = c;
                        string newWord = newWordBuilder.ToString();
                        if (Dictionary.Contains(newWord))
                        {
                            //avoid traversing a previously traversed node
                            if (!parents.Keys.Contains(newWord))
                            {
                                parents.Add(newWord.ToString(), s);
                                nextFrontier.Add(newWord);
                            }

                        }
                        if (newWord.ToString() == end)
                        {
                            return ExtractPath(start, end);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            currentFrontier.Clear();
            currentFrontier.Concat(nextFrontier);
            nextFrontier.Clear();
        }
        throw new ArgumentException("The given dictionary cannot be used to get a path from start to end");
    }

    private static List<string> ExtractPath(string start,string end)
    {
        List<string> path = new List<string>();
        string current = end;
        path.Add(end);
        while (current != start)
        {
            current = parents[current];
            path.Add(current);
        }
         path.Reverse();
         return path;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we need graph or some other complicated data structure. My idea is to load the dictionary as a `HashSet` and use `contains()` method to find out if the word exists in the dictionary or not.

Please, check this **pseudocode** to see my idea:

```
Two words are given: START and STOP. 
//List is our "way" from words START to STOP, so, we add the original word to it first.
    list.add(START);
//Finish to change the word when START equals STOP.
    while(!START.equals(STOP))
//Change each letter at START to the letter to STOP one by one and check if such word exists.
    for (int i = 0, i<STOP.length, i++){
        char temp = START[i];
        START[i] = STOP[i];
//If the word exists add a new word to the list of results. 
//And change another letter in the new word with the next pass of the loop.
        if dictionary.contains(START)
           list.add(START)
//If the word doesn't exist, leave it like it was and try to change another letter with the next pass of the loop.
        else START[i] = temp;}
    return list;
```

As I understand my code should work like that:

**Input**: DAMP, LIKE

**Output**: DAMP, LAMP, LIMP, LIME, LIKE

**Input**: BACK, PICK

**Output**: BACK, PACK, PICK

Comment: What if your dictionary only contains: DAMP, JAMP, JIMP, JIME, JIKE, LIKE? My point is, you may have some intermediary words that are in the dictionary but has different letters than the source and target words.

Comment: Will this guarantee the shortest path ?

Answer (score -1):

```
class Solution {
    //static int ans=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    public int ladderLength(String beginWord, String endWord, List<String> wordList) {
        HashMap<String,Integer> h=new HashMap<String,Integer>();
        HashMap<String,Integer> h1=new HashMap<String,Integer>();
        for(int i=0;i<wordList.size();i++)
        {
            h1.put(wordList.get(i),1);
        }
        int count=0;
        Queue<String> q=new LinkedList<String>();
        q.add(beginWord);
        q.add("-1");
        h.put(beginWord,1);
        int ans=ladderLengthUtil(beginWord,endWord,wordList,h,count,q,h1);
        return ans;
    }
    public int ladderLengthUtil(String beginWord, String endWord, List<String> wordList,HashMap<String,Integer> h,int count,Queue<String> q,HashMap<String,Integer> h1)
    {  
        int ans=1;
        while(!q.isEmpty()) 
        {
            String s=q.peek();
            q.poll();
            if(s.equals(endWord))
            {
                return ans;   
            }
            else if(s.equals("-1"))
            {
                if(q.isEmpty())
                {                    
                    break;
                }
                ans++;                
                q.add("-1");
            }
            else
            {
                for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
                {
                        for(int j=0;j<26;j++)
                        {
                            char a=(char)('a'+j);
                            String s1=s.substring(0,i)+a+s.substring(i+1);
                            //System.out.println("s1 is "+s1);
                            if(h1.containsKey(s1)&&!h.containsKey(s1))
                            {
                                h.put(s1,1);
                                q.add(s1);
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;    
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. Unfortunately you code is not formatted correctly. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for further information.

Answer (score -3):

This is clearly a permutation problem. Using a graph is overkill. The problem statment is missing one important constraint; ***that you can change each position only once***. This then makes it implicit that the solution is within 4 steps. Now all that needs to be decided is the sequence of the replace operations:

Operation1 = change "H" to "T"
Operation2 = change "E" to "A"
Operation3 = change "A" to "I"
Operation4 = change "D to "L"

The solution, the sequence of operations, is some permutation of the string "1234", where each digit represents the position of the character being replaced. e.g. "3124" indicates that first we apply operation3, then operation1, then operation2, then operation 4. At each step, if resulting word is not in dictionary, skip to next permutation. Reasonably trivial. Code anyone?

Comment: I think he left out that constraint because it isn't one of the constraints.

Comment: it increases the complexity to n^n