# String transformation

Tags: string, algorithm

I came across the following [article](http://www.glassdoor.com/Interview/Given-two-words-CAT-FAR-determine-if-you-can-get-from-the-first-to-the-second-via-single-transformations-of-valid-word-QTN_172828.htm) which got me interested in this particular problem.

> Given two words "CAT", "FAR" determine if you can get from the first
>   to the second via single transformations of valid words....e.g. 1
>   transformation gets you from CAT to CAR changing T to R, then another
>   gets you from CAR to FAR changing the C to F...all are valid english
>   words.

Any ideas? Not really sure how to begin to be honest. If you point me in the right direction, then that will be enough. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shortest path to transform one word into another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521958/shortest-path-to-transform-one-word-into-another)

Comment: ah, thanks aix. do you agree with that answer, though, that a* is the best choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521958/shortest-path-to-transform-one-word-into-another/1521973#1521973) (thanks, aix), this is a shortest-path problem, and can be efficiently solved with the [A* algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) using the [Hamming distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) (i.e. the number of letters by which two words differ) as a heuristic.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 points to consider :

1 How many characters are different between the two given words ? Its just not the char, but its position in the word also matters. So compare on position.

2 Determine for each transformation , if the resulting word is a valid english word. Some  reference of correct words will be needed here.

3 Work out the sequence of transforms that each intermediate word is valid.

This is going to be a try-err approach I guess. Any backtracking algorithm will be a good choice.